# Can I change the default size of a new table in macOS Pages?

Tags: pages

In Pages, I frequently have to make documents (for school) with a two by five table.  Each time I click the table button, I then have to resize the table.  Can I change the default table size, so each new table is automatically two by five?

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options available to you, such as creating a template, using AppleScript or Automator to create applications, scripts, or services, and so on.

Below is a sample script I've created based on the details in your question:

```
tell application "Pages"
set myDoc to make new document
tell page 1 of myDoc to set myTable to make new table with properties {column count:5, row count:2}
tell cell range of myTable
    set width of columns to 80
    set text wrap to true
    set alignment to left

end tell
end tell
```

Assuming you're not familiar with how to use this, below is one way you could use the above script:

**Create a service using Automator**

1. Launch Automator (usually found within your Applications folder)
2. Go to **File > New**
3. Select **Service** and click the <kbd>Choose</kbd> button (**Note:** If the 'Service' option is not available, select Quick Action instead)
4. In the top right hand of the window that appears, ensure that "No input" is selected from the *Service receives* drop-down list
5. Ensure the *In* drop-down list is showing "Any application"
6. In the second column containing the long list, find "Run AppleScript" and double-click on it
7. This will add the Run AppleScript window on the right
8. Now, **replace** the (* Your script goes here *) with the the sample script above
9. Save the service using a meaningful name (e.g. Create Pages Table).

Now you should be able to run the service from *any* application by going to the Services list within any Application menu (e.g. Pages > Services, Finder > Services, etc) and select the service you just created.

**NOTES:**

- The `set width`, `set text wrap` and `set alignment` lines within the script are not required. I have included these so you know how to customise these table characteristics if you need to.
- I have assumed from your question that your two by five table referred to five columns by two rows. However, you can safely change the `column count` and `row count` values in the script to suit your requirements.